# WordPress pagination repeating first page

Tags: php, wordpress

This use to work, until wordpress updated and now the pagination on a custom page is repeating the first page. Page 2 for example will just show up page 1 content.

I've been looking and looking and nothing is helping.

I'm calling wordpress functions outside of wordpress install with

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

then the wordpress loop is (and it's probably outdated and faulty, but this was the only one that worked at the time)

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) : 1;
       $args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 20,
           //'showposts' => 20,
'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
    'paged' => $paged,
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )      

);

query_posts( $args); ?>

  <?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/includes/producttemplate.php";
   include_once($path);
?>

</div>
<br class="clear" />
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="pagination">
<p><br /><?php pagination_bar($args); if(!$_GET['viewall']){ ?>

<br />
<a class="all" href="<?php  echo add_query_arg( array( 'view' => 'all' ), get_pagenum_link(1) ); ?>">Show All</a><br /></p>
<?php } }?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and then my custom pagination function is

```
//Pagenation
function pagination_bar() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
 $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $paged,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you needing to call wordpress functions from outside of wordpress? What is it you are actually *doing* outside of WP?

Comment: it was just the way the site was originally set up. Wordpress was installed in a different directory to kind of mask the fact that it was using wordpress and to keep the filing system neat and tidy. And since then the site has just been built on top of that (eventually it'll be redone and reorganised). It's been moved back to the main directory since, but it's just easier to edit the old pages then rebuilt new ones

Comment: So essentially your themes/views are now outside WP and are including WP to use the functionality?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: You'll have a hard time getting any support for that. Chances are, the issue is related to how you are handling wordpress ;)

Comment: well it worked perfectly fine beforehand. and there's another external page with a pagination and that one works fine it's just this one that doesn't.

Comment: I may be wrong with my previous comment - please see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The following are two lines copied out of your second code dump:

```
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
```

Notice the query_var is `paged`?
Now, have a look at this copy from the first line of the first dump:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) : 1;
```

Notice the difference? `page`, instead of `paged`.

Comment: yeah I just fiddled around with this, nothing. Changed them all to paged, nothing. Removed it from the function and replaced it with 'current' => $current_page, and nothing. I thought it might be because the page is in directory (products/firepits.php) and moved it to the main directory like the news.php page and still nothing.

Comment: I figured it out, it was require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); it needs require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'charters',
    'cat'=> $cat,
    'post_per_page'=> 6, 
    'paged' => $paged 
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p><?php
        endwhile;
    }

    wp_reset_query();

?>

<?php echo pnavigation( $query ); ?>
```

then you need to add following code to function.php :

```
function pnavigation( $wp_query ) {

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
  $pages = paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
  'prev_next' => false,
  'type'  => 'array',
  'prev_next'   => TRUE,
  'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
  'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
  ) );
  if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
    echo '<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
      echo "<li>$page</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

also add this code to function.php, you need to just replace url (client-testimonials) with your page url

```
function pagination_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('client-testimonials/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=client-testimonials&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'pagination_rewrite');
```

Answer (score 0):

After pulling whats left of my hair out, I solved it. It was this part

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Needs to be

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

I'm currently using both as a fallback. I don't know if it needs to just be one. If someone has more info if it's safe to use both?